# Cross domain tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am first time posting something here...

Issue:
We have moved to Universal Analytics few month back and since then form submission conversion attribution is broken. Almost all conversions (form submission) are attributed to direct traffic. Actually we have our confirmation page on third domain (now.eloqua.com) but it has the same code as we have on the website. But I guess due to different domains, cookies are getting drop in transition from main website to the confirmation page as analytics.js does not set up _utm cookies

Possible Solution, is I guess using Cross Domain Auto Linking (auto link plugin), We have implemented below code on both main website page and Thank you page (eloqua.com).. but issue still persists. Can somebody suggest what wrong I am doing here...

```
function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-X', 'auto',{'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['eloqua.com']); 
ga('send', 'pageview')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that your conversions are form submission you might have to add another parameter to the call to the autolinker plugin (this is as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#autolink), I have not tested this):

> Cross Domain Auto Linking for Forms
>
> Universal Analytics also includes the ability cross domain link 
>   elements automatically. ga('linker:autoLink', ['destination.com',
>   'dest3.com'], false, true);

Where the third parameter (false) tell the autolinker to **not** use the anchor/hash and the fourth parameter tells it to auto-decorate form action urls (else only links get decorated), so this is what you need. You should see a _ga parameter appended to the urls on arrival at the other domain if this is working correctly.

Plus I'm reasonably sure that you need to add both domains to your referral exclusion list.

Comment: Hi Eike, Thanks so much the reply!I still struggling to fix this issue. we have following code on the site right now:
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-X', 'auto',{'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['main-site.com','dest.com'], true, true); 
  ga('send', 'pageview')
as per ur suggestion I noticed that we have to use 'false' for the third parameter & another thing is you did not use the main-site.com in the code line. Actually we thought of having one code on both pages,so we included main-site.com in the array,does it make any diff? what should be our code?

Comment: Also I am not sure if this would impact but a typical journey on the site with form submission would be like - main-site.com homepage >> membership form hosted on main-site.com >> thank you page hosted on dest.com >> redirected back to main-site.com homepage..